# Xml messages processing networkstream

Tags: c#, xml, event-handling, stream, tcp

I'm currently processing xml messages with C#. It is working But I'm not confident that my code is fast enough. There are 3 possible messages I can receive. When I receive one the message an event is triggered and I can access the object outside of this thread and do the necessary processing. The method start is running in a separate thread.

```
    public void Start()
    {
        NameTable nt = new NameTable();
        object frameAck = nt.Add("frameack");
        object alarmResponse = nt.Add("alarmresponse");
        object watchdog = nt.Add("watchdog");
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(_tcpClient.GetStream());
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings
        {
            NameTable = nt,
            ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment
        };
        XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(sr, settings);
        while (!_requestStop)
        {
            try
            {
                while (xr.Read())
                {
                    if (xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                    {
                        object localName = xr.LocalName; // Cache the local name to prevent multiple calls to the LocalName property.
                        if (watchdog == localName)
                            OnWatchdogComplete(new CustomEventArgs(xr.ToClassFromXmlStream<WatchdogFrame>()));
                        if (alarmResponse == localName)
                            OnAlarmResponseComplete(new CustomEventArgs(xr.ToClassFromXmlStream<AlarmResponse>()));
                        if (frameAck == localName)
                            OnAckComplete(new CustomEventArgs(xr.ToClassFromXmlStream<FrameAck>()));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
        xr.Close();
        sr.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Stopping TcpXmlReader thread!");
    }
```

This is my extensionmethod to deserialize to an object.

```
    public static T ToClassFromXmlStream<T>(this XmlReader xmlStream)
    {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T)serializer.Deserialize(xmlStream);
    }
```

When I close the program I always get the errors:

> There is an error in XML document (9, 12).
>
> Cannot access a disposed object.
>
> Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.

When I was string processing this it would seem that is was going a lot faster. But it was very complex and this very easy.

Comment: Your question is currently off-topic because you involve broken code (Asking why you get errors when you close the application). If you can fix this (hint, there's something that is `IDisposable` in there probably), it will be a very good fit on Code Review! :)

Comment: Fixed broken code.

Comment: Please see: [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765). I realize that you edit fixed problems in the code to make the question back on-topic, but since the question is also answered, the question is in 'limbo', and answer-invalidation "outweighs" being on-topic. The correct approach here would be to put the working code in a new question as a "follow on" (see the link...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this question is half-way between Stack Overflow and Code Review anyway...

`Start()` is running on a standalone thread however it uses `_tcpClient`. Assuming things are properly done you dispose `_tcpClient` in container class `Dispose()` method. When it happens your reader will access (indirectly, through `sr` of type `StreamReader`) a disposed object (`_tcpClient`, from which underlying stream comes from).

You may transfer ownership of `_tcpClient` to your secondary thread.

```
void Start() {
    try {
        // All the code you already have in-place
    }
    finally {
        _tcpClient.Dispose();
    }
}
```

However you already have a flag in-place (`_requestStop`). Hard to say (without surrounding code) what's wrong but you first should check if you set flag `_requestStop` and immediately exit (even if reading is in progress). You'd better set that flag and then wait until thread completes its work (for an example see [How to wait for thread to finish with .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1584062/1207195)).

---

Few more considerations more on-topic on Code Review.

1) You're not using `using` statement:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(_tcpClient.GetStream())) {
    // You don't need to explicitly call sr.Close();
}
```

Do the same for your `XmlReader` variable `xr`.

2) XML deserialization isn't as quick as you may wish. If speed is a measured issue then you may consider to manually parse XML fragment (using `XmlReader` you have) to build your objects.

3) You should avoid to catch a generic `Exception`. You should know what may go wrong in your code, catch errors you expect and leave to a more generic error handler to catch the others (for example, no matters how many times you retry because of `while()` but if `_tcpClient` has been closed then it won't recover its connection and you'll keep generating exceptions).

4) In your big `try`/`catch` you also catch exceptions generated by code called in *events*. Also some exceptions may leave `XmlReader` in an inconsistent state and you may want to re-create it.

5) You do not need to *cache* `XmlReader.LocalName` property value. It won't perform any parsing for each access and call to property getter may be optimized away (inlined) by JIT compiler. It's such micro-optimization that you won't notice any difference even if you read its value `Int32.MaxValue` times (do not forget you're also working with network data).

6) `XmlReader.LocalName` type is `string`, no reason to loose its type assigning to an `object` variable. The same is true for `NameTable.Add()` return type: it's a string, don't assign it to an *untyped* `object` variable.

7) You compare strings (`localName` with `watchdog` and the others) but you do not explicitly say which type of comparison you want. Is it case-sensitive or case-insensitive? Is current culture aware? Make it explicit according to what you want or you may have surprises when current culture has *unexpected* text comparison rules (see also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27229589/1207195)). Change your code to:

```
if (String.Equals(xr.LocalName, watchdog, StringComparison.InvariantCulture)) {
}
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "manually parse XML fragment"? I can't exactly figure out what you mean by it.

Comment: I mean: do what XmlSerializer does, reading node by node while advancing the stream. XmlSerializer is pretty fast if you also deploy serialization assemblies (generated with sgen) otherwise its _bootstrapping_ made with Reflection will slow down a lot your code. Internally it uses XmlReader but of course it's a general implementation so scenario-specific code will be faster.

Comment: So you mean something like [this](http://goo.gl/M8P033) (listing 3). Or something like this. 
`class CarResource
{
    public string Color { get; private set; }

    private void ReadFrom(XmlReader xml)
    {
        this.Color = xml.GetAttribute("colour");
    }
}`

Comment: Yes! Note that it may be not an issue, if you worry about performance it's something you should be aware but before doing anything you'd better profile your code (if, because of network latency, you wait - in average - 50 ms and you need 1 ms to deserialize then I wouldn't worry at all).

Comment: I can say that the manual deserializing is going a lot faster from 1.6s - 6.6s (auto deserializing) to almost 2-3ms with manual transalation.

Comment: If ~1 sec or more then you're also measuring bootstrapping time (when it builds a C# class to deserialize XML, the same code - more or less - you're writing now by hand). If you deploy serializazion assemblies (generated with sgen) then this time will drop to something comparable to your manually written code (even if probably your code will still be slightly faster).

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the performance, but you should make sure your resources get closed properly when an exception occurs. Either switch to a using statement, or move your clean up code to a finally block.